# How to analyze an unhandled exception, caught by VS2010 in debug mode?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging, exception

My C++ program throw exception that is unhandled in a program, so in debug mode the VS handles it, showing a window about the fact that unhandled exception is occured. But can i view this exception, that is unhandled? What its type, what is inside the object being throwh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try hitting Break and stepping into. If there's anything to be analysed code-wise, then VS will step into the handler or a constructor of the exception class. This is how I've been doing in VS2010, anyway.

From that point, if you got to know the address of the exception object, then you should be able to paste it into the Watch window and cast to a base exception class (if the exception is not a system exception and you've got a good class hierarchy).

P.S.
You can have your own unhandled exception routine to set your break point inside of it. Can be as simple as:

```
// global scope
    LONG WINAPI my_unh_exc_hndlr(_EXCEPTION_POINTERS* excPtrs)
    {
        return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH; // Put a breakpoint here in IDE.
    }

// ... somewhere in the beginning of main()
    SetUnhandledExceptionFilter(my_unh_exc_hndlr);
```

Should run each time you hit an unhandled exception.

Another program crashing randomly? No source available? No problem. Inject code (small DLL) that sets the handler routine for you there (unless you have less privileges) and debug.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases when an exception occurs, Visual Studio should bring up a dialogue box with the option to break your program, enabling you to see where it occurred in your code. Furthermore you should be able to analyse the values of objects, pointers and whatnot right before the exception occurred. This should be sufficient enough to get an idea of what is going wrong (unless you're dealing with a heap corruption or something nasty like that). It's hard to say more without knowing the specifics of the exception itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't see all the information for the exception, you might want to check your debug settings in Visual Studio. Go to the Debug menu and click Exceptions... From there you can choose to break on all exceptions. This should force the debugger to break as soon as possible when the exception occurs.